# The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace - without reference

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, namespaces

I encountered a strange problem (Visual Studio 2012):

"The type or namespace name 'X' does not exist in the namespace 'XX.X' (are you missing an assembly reference?) ...\MyUserControl.g.cs ....

I have the following user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="xxxxxx.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=h}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Foreground="Black" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=hd}" FontSize="12" Margin="10,10,0,5" MaxWidth="250" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="Auto" Foreground="Black"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

and when I try to build the project the **.g.cs** file insists to add namespace that does not exist in references, and do not use it in any way in xaml.

I tried to make a clean and rebuild.. nothing helps.

Usually such problems are when the namespace is not written correctly, but here I have no reference to any other namespace, so it is strange.

Anyone else having this problem and can help?

Comment: Try to copy the contents of the UserControl to the clipboard, delete the UserControl, create a new one and paste in the contents from the clipboard. Do the same for any code-behind you may have. And Close the .g.cs file. And rebuild.

Comment: @mm8 I tried, also did not help :(

Comment: You should check whether there are some namespaces defined in your XAML that reference this unrecognized assembly.

Comment: Your XAML code seems to me perfect just do one thing create a new project and try to build it again

Comment: Maybe it's in a "Styles.xaml" or "Generic.xaml". Have you tried to "Find in Files"?

Comment: @mat thank you very much!!! it's work, I find reference in Generic.xaml. Can you upload answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mat's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/70681378) helped me with the problem: I found reference in `Generic.xaml`.